# Google.OR-Tools in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure-functions, or-tools

I've been working with OR-Tools in Python recently and have been attempting to move my code to an Azure Function in Python. Does anyone know if this is supported?

I've tried and keep getting issues where I am unable to import OR-Tools Modules (specifically pywrapcp & routing_enums_pb2 from ortools.constraint_solver). I have confirmed my Python version is 64bit.

According to the OR-Tools distro it supports Linux, however I've been reading around & it seems it could be to do with C++ redistributables needing to be installed. This is where I am now completely out of my depth & could use some pointers. Is this possible in a python function?

****Edit****

Following Bowman Zhu's comment below - I've checked that ORTools exists in my environment - see snip below. The script is failing at the poitn where I try import pywrapcp.

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
```

But it's definitely there. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hi, any update of this question? Have you activate the virtual env?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem:

[image]

And my python version is also 64bit:

[image]

Maybe you are reading this document of google tools:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/python/windows

Tips: I have already install the C++ redistributables you mentioned, but still get this error. I check the Libs of the azure function and it doesn't have ortools module.

I think the answer is virtual environment really dont have this module:

[image]

you need to run this command to install ortools on your virtual environment:

```
pip install ortools
```

Then ortools will be in the virtual environment, import also no longer return error any more:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my post to show the libraries installed & ORTools is definitely in there.

Comment: @stephen.webb If it is in the libs, it should can be import. Do you activate the virtual environment when you try to start function host? This is the powershell on my side: [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyJkG.png), [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTHXU.png)

Comment: @stephen.webb Try start the .venv virtual env manully and run `func host start`. That should be no problem.

Comment: @stephen.webb I create a simple case and it works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBsY1.png So I think the problem comes from the virtual env didn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly on our or-tools mailing list or github issue:

- or-tools is a native python (python part is just a SWIG wrapper on top of it) library and currently we can only build it using VS 2019 (since VS 2017 compiler crash SO)
- you must install the VS C++ redistributable 2019 since the c++ library depend on it
- Azure image don't have VS Redistributable 2019 yet AFAIK
- when python interpreter try to load the native lib, it can't find all dependencies and you have this error message...

Comment: Or-Tools is native C++

Comment: Python functions run only on Linux in Azure, so no C++ redistributables are required.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working - Python Azure Function running OR-Tools.

In my testing I can think of two possible reasons for your problem (I wasn't sure if you were having local problems, or problems once deployed);

- You're using a locally installed python interpreter instead of the version that lives here `.\.venv\Scripts\python.exe` so the pylint can't find the venv copies of the dependencies.
- You're missing including `ortools` in the `requirements.txt` so it's not getting installed server side on deployment.

This is what causes Azure to install the dependencies when you deploy the function. You don't need to include them manually;

```
# DO NOT include azure-functions-worker in this file
# The Python Worker is managed by Azure Functions platform
# Manually managing azure-functions-worker may cause unexpected issues

azure-functions
ortools
```

A couple of things to note;

- OR-Tools is native C++ with wrappers for everything else.
- Python functions run only on Linux in Azure, so no C++ redistributables are required server side.
- Installing the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash) for Visual Studio Code on Windows will allow you to debug your Python Azure Function locally (I'm assuming this does require the C++ redistributables for local Windows execution).
- I used the Visual Studio extension "Azure Functions" for deployment.

I basically followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python), then added OR-Tools to `requirements.txt` and added a [simple sample solve](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/python) for testing locally, then deployed and tested server side.

Answer (score 0):

i'm facing the same issue.

I've included ortools in my requirements.txt file:

```
azure-functions
ortools
```

When I deploy a 'hello word' sample function I can see that the modules are being installed ok:

```
Successfully installed absl-py-1.4.0 azure-functions-1.15.0 numpy-1.25.0 ortools-9.6.2534 protobuf-4.23.3 scipy-1.11.0
```

And the HTTP triggers is registered ok.
But if i try to import pywrapcp from ortools in the .py sample function and deploy again I get the error **No HTTP triggers found.** and no other errors in the deploy log.

(if I run locally the function (*func host start*) (with a VRP problem solving) everything works ok.)

The problem arise when deploying to azure function.

source code:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="HttpTrigger2", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def HttpTrigger2(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

name = req.params.get('name')
if not name:
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        name = req_body.get('name')

if name:
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
else:
    return func.HttpResponse(
         "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
         status_code=200
    )
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34603422)